# Magento2: Label alignment in Dashboard Chart

Tags: magento2, dashboard, chart

[image]

I want y-axis value on-line .how can I do this

Answer (score 0):

Please check with hre to list of all *-axis class exist :

to do with css for alignment change here path :

```
vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/Report/Html/Renderer/Template/css/nv.d3.min.css
```

Comment: It's an image created from code in Graph.php
I can't align it via CSS